# Как записать выступление на конференции

Tags: видео

Видел на YouTube выступления с IT конференций, где одновременно в кадре присутствует презентация выступающего и сам выступающий. Пример: https://youtu.be/zWTEo8RJtMo Хочу узнать:

1. Как это делается?
2. Есть ли какое-нибудь средство автоматизации для этого?
3. Как синхронизируются слайды презентации с видео выступающего?

А так же любой опыт в этой области, включая необходимое оборудование.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ссылку на youtube с образцом доклада, запись которого соответствует вашим требованиям. Вопрос выглядит офф-топик, но может быть его можно спасти.

Comment: Например такое https://youtu.be/zWTEo8RJtMo

Comment: Лучше отредактируйте пост, добавив туда эту ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Советую обратить внимание на http://createwebinar.com
Дружественный интерфейс приаттачен к BigBlueButton. Есть 3 вида вебинаров: открытый для всех; закрытый - по списку; и с подтверждением. Можно создать контакт лист  для быстрого оповещения. Прошедший вебинар можно просматривать онлайн или скачать видеофайл на свой компьютер. Все базовые функции бесплатны.
Кириллические тексты разрешены, для мобильных устройств на IOS - HTML5.

Comment: Не могли бы вы по возможности дополнить ответ примером?

Answer (score 0):

Есть множество сервисов для вебинаров, например clickmeeting, adobe connect, bigbluebutton и пр. Большинство их них позволяет делать запись. Можно проводить выступление используя их - за одно и проблема с трансляцией в сеть решится.

Либо, записываем видео выступления, берем презентацию и в любом видео-редакторе монтируем все это вместе так, как вам нужно

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, интерисует именно живое выступление человека с презентацией для аудитории и запись этого для размещения в Интернете.

Comment: "Либо, записываем видео выступления, берем презентацию и в любом видео-редакторе монтируем все это вместе так, как вам нужно" - можете подробней раскрыть этот вариант. Мне видется проблема времени показа слайдов, для ее решения я бы захватывал видео с ноутбука, которого ведется презентация, потом сводил 2 видео потока. Насколько это рабочее решение?

Comment: @user3192683 зависит от того, как много записей придется делать. Самый лучший вариант - монтировать все вручную, тогда не придется лишний раз записывать кучу не нужных видео с презентациями, да и качество возрастет. Но, если вам нужно будет выложить большое количество записей, то проще снять экран со слайдами, свести 2 потока вначале и приступить к следующему - это существенно сэкономит время.